# any function in R to calculate difference between each next cell value?

Tags: r

I have this data and is there any function which calculate  difference between each next cell value  ?

input DATA>

```
"date","value"
2020-01-22,10
2020-01-23,15
2020-01-24,25
2020-01-25,27
2020-01-26,33
```

expected OUTPUT>

```
2020-01-22,10
2020-01-23,5
2020-01-24,10
2020-01-25,2
2020-01-26,6
```

Comment: did you mean for the first row difference to be `10`? Should it be `0` instead?

Comment: sorry, I put 10 because it is first in row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is the `diff` in `base R`

```
df1$newvalue <- c(df1$value[1], diff(df1$value))
df1$newvalue
#[1] 10  5 10  2  6
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(date = c("2020-01-22", "2020-01-23", "2020-01-24", 
"2020-01-25", "2020-01-26"), value = c(10L, 15L, 25L, 27L, 33L
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Comment: Thanks to all, I used this option and its working, however can you please explain how it works ?   `c(df1$value[1], diff(df1$value)) `  what means  this ?  `c(df1$value[1]`  starting from 1st ?

Comment: @Andrew if you have a vector of values i.e. column `v1 <- c(5, 3, 2)`, when you apply `diff`, it returns length one less than the original vector `diff(v1)` by taking the difference of adjacent element.  Concatenate with the first element (`c(v1[1], diff(v1))` to get the length correct

Answer (score 0):

Another solution. You can use `lag` to find the previous value

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>% 
  mutate(out = value - lag(value, default = 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

No dependencies needed, just subtract the first lag:

```
> df <- data.frame(x = letters[1:5], value = c(2, 5, 8, 11, 15))
> df$value <- df$value - lag(df$value, lag = 1)
> df
  x value
1 a    NA
2 b     3
3 c     3
4 d     3
5 e     4
```